# Visual themes and Delphi 7 on Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, themes, delphi-7

how I can enable using visual themes for Delphi 7 IDE on Windows 7? For Windows XP I made file delphi32.exe.manifest, but for Windows 7 it does not work.

I mean Delphi 7 enviroment and development. My programs are OK.

Thank you, Pavel

Answer (score 2):

You should never include any manifest for the Delphi IDE executable file. This will trigger errors during the execution process of you apps (mainly if you use TImageList component).
So use the old "Win NT" layout of the IDE. It's enough.
In order to work with Windows 7, two steps to be performed:
1. Make the "Borland" or "Borland\Delphi" folder accessible to all users as WRITE from its properties (and sub folders, of course)
2. Install the old Windows Help and some Delphi 7 IDE enhancements, as I stated in http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/01/01/Some

Comment: Yes, It is very usefull. But I miss "new look" with themes for designing. In WinXP it works fine.

Comment: About ImageList crash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074857/image-list-loading-fails-on-delphi-6-and-vista-service-pack-2

Comment: From what I've read in other places, the issues with adding a manifest to the IDE were sorted from Delphi 7.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you drop a XPManifest control on the mainform?

Comment: I mean Delphi 7 enviroment and development. My programs are OK.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using separate .menifest file - then identify section of manifest should match your exe file. If you got it wrong - the manifest will be ignored. Identity section is ignored, if manifest is compiled into executable. So, if you can't get it working - add it as resource, not as file.

Why it works in XP? Don't know. May be W7 have more strict checks than WXP or something similar.

But I don't think that applying a manifest to D7 is a good idea. Why don't you use D2007 or D2010? Let D7 rest in peace, really.

Comment: Because it is really huge project contains many applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is an informed solution, though I haven't tested it (I don't use Delphi 7 anymore)...

You need to create a Package, and that package required DesignIDE. In your package, add a unit (doesn't matter what you call it)... now put the following code in your unit:

```
unit D7WithTheme;

interface

uses
  XPMan;

var
  D7Theme: TXPManifest;

implementation

initialization
  D7Theme := TXPManifest.Create(nil);
finalization
  D7Theme.Free;
```

Save and install your package... you should now have OS theming when you load the IDE! Hope it helps!

Comment: actually I'll do you one better... I'll install Delphi 7 and build the package for you, then post a link here when I'm done. Sound good?

Comment: @Pavel I'm working on a universal IDE Modernization Plugin, which (amongst other things) will resolve this issue. I'll post another comment on here when it's online.

Answer (score -2):

You should compile the manifest as resource inside of the executable.

Comment: How do you recompile the Delphi IDE (unless you work for Embarcadero)?

Comment: Welcome r4w8173, the question was specifically how to get the IDE to theme correctly in windows 7, not an executable compiled within the IDE.

Comment: actually I have successfully put the manifest inside the Delphi32.exe with a resource editor :).

that said I must add that it is not very useful thing to do since all the lists and tool images got the same boring delphi 7 style.